# Define a schema for a Dataframe before writing to a Kafka Topic using scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, schema

I have the following dataframe (finalDataFrame) schema

```
 root
     |-- sentence: string (nullable = true)
     |-- category: string (nullable = true)
     |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
```

And I have defined the following schema

```
def defineS3SinkSchema() : StructType = {
    new StructType()
      .add("payload", new StructType()
        .add("sentence", StringType)
        .add("Id", LongType)
        .add("category", StringType)
        )
  }
```

I want to use the above schema to the dataframe defined in the above and write to a kafka topic.
But im not sure how to integrate defined schema with the dataframe. Following is the code to write to kafka topic.

```
val jsonFormatData = finalDataFrame.select(col("key").cast("string").alias("key"),
      to_json(struct(
        col("sentence"),
        col("category"),
        col("key").as("Id")
      )).alias("value"))
    jsonFormatData.printSchema()
    val writeStream = jsonFormatData
      .writeStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", hostAddress)
      .option("topic", "myTopic.val")
      .option("checkpointLocation", "test_path")
      .start()
    writeStream.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Have you consider to use Avro?

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 can you point me to an example?

Comment: sure. Take a look to https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-streaming-consume-and-produce-kafka-messages-in-avro-format/